# How can I check for domain.com or sub.domain.com?

Tags: php, http

I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` & `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, but they both return **sub.domain.com**, I want it to check if the URL is *sub.domain.com*, or *just domain.com*.

Script is run on sub.domain.com and they BOTH return the same data.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` returns: sub.domain.com
`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` returns: sub.domain.com

I wish to obtain only the domain.com portion of the url. Since the script may run on any subdomain name, I am unsure of how to do so since both of the above variables return the same information.

Comment: Which one where for what and when?  - `HTTP_HOST` *should* be the one you're looking for.

Comment: If they both return sub.domain.com, why do you need to check anything? You know it will be sub.domain.com and not domain.com.

Comment: @Quentin The script will be run on several different sub domains, or some even without a sub domain. It needs to know whether the URL is a subdomain or just a TLD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check HTTP_HOST. Usually both are the same, but sometimes SERVER_NAME is set differently. When in doubt, check them both.

> **'HTTP_HOST'**
>   Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

As for how to check them, you could do a string replace on it for the primary domain name and see if the result string is empty. Anything left would be the subdomain.

---

As far you're looking for some trivial string operation, here the last two parts:

```
$yourhost = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']), -2));
```

Comment: they BOTH return sub.domain.com.

Comment: @Michael Ecklund: You worded your question a bit esoteric the first time, I added some code example for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the function below (found on php.net)

```
<?php 
function getHost($Address) { 
$parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
return trim($parseUrl[host] ? $parseUrl[host] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl[path],     2))); 
} 

getHost("example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("http://example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("www.example.com"); // Gives www.example.com 
getHost("http://example.com/xyz"); // Gives example.com 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little dirty *hack*:

```
$explodedHost = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$size         = count($explodedHost);
$domain       = $explodedHost[$size - 2] . '.' . $explodedHost[$size - 1] . 'com';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $domain) {
  // you are on domain.com
}
```